# "In" operator for numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, operators

How can I do the "in" operation on a numpy array?
(Return True if an element is present in the given numpy array)

For strings, lists and dictionaries, the functionality is intuitive to understand.

Here's what I got when I applied that on a numpy array

```
a
array([[[2, 3, 0],
    [1, 0, 1]],

   [[3, 2, 0],
    [0, 1, 1]],

   [[2, 2, 0],
    [1, 1, 1]],

   [[1, 3, 0],
    [2, 0, 1]],

   [[3, 1, 0],
    [0, 2, 1]]])

b = [[3, 2, 0],
    [0, 1, 1]]

b in a
True
#Aligned with the expectation

c = [[300, 200, 0],
    [0, 100, 100]]

c in a
True
#Not quite what I expected
```

Comment: For 1d arrays there is a `np.in1d`, but applying it to rows of a 2d array requires some tricks.  Look at it's code to see what is involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could compare the input arrays for `equality`, which will perform [`broadcasted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) comparisons across all elements in `a` at each position in the last two axes against elements at corresponding positions in the second array. This will result in a boolean array of matches, in which we check for [`ALL`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) matches across the last two axes and finally check for [`ANY`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) match, like so -

```
((a==b).all(axis=(1,2))).any()
```

**Sample run**

1) Inputs :

```
In [68]: a
Out[68]: 
array([[[2, 3, 0],
        [1, 0, 1]],

       [[3, 2, 0],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 3, 0],
        [2, 0, 1]],

       [[3, 1, 0],
        [0, 2, 1]]])

In [69]: b
Out[69]: 
array([[3, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])
```

2) Broadcasted elementwise comparisons :

```
In [70]: a==b
Out[70]: 
array([[[False, False,  True],
        [False, False,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[False,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True]],

       [[False, False,  True],
        [False, False,  True]],

       [[ True, False,  True],
        [ True, False,  True]]], dtype=bool)
```

3) `ALL` match across last two axes and finally `ANY` match :

```
In [71]: (a==b).all(axis=(1,2))
Out[71]: array([False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [72]: ((a==b).all(axis=(1,2))).any()
Out[72]: True
```

Following similar steps for `c` in `a` -

```
In [73]: c
Out[73]: 
array([[300, 200,   0],
       [  0, 100, 100]])

In [74]: ((a==c).all(axis=(1,2))).any()
Out[74]: False
```

Comment: Thanks for saving the day! So no straightforward way like "in" to check the existence on a numpy array?

Comment: @akilat90 I am afraid there isn't. Or just wrap it into a function and there you go, a custom made `straightforward` way!

Answer (score 2):

This question is fairly old, but if you're like me, you might have thought there was no numpy equivalent for *in* by reading it.

Numpy 1.13 was released in 2017, and with it came the function [*isin()*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html?highlight=isin#numpy.isin), which now nicely solves the problem:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[2, 3, 0],
               [1, 0, 1]],
              [[3, 2, 0],
               [0, 1, 1]],
              [[2, 2, 0],
               [1, 1, 1]],
              [[1, 3, 0],
               [2, 0, 1]],
              [[3, 1, 0],
               [0, 2, 1]]])

b = [[3, 2, 0],
     [0, 1, 1]]

print np.isin(b,a)

# [[ True  True  True]
#  [ True  True  True]]

c = [[300, 200, 0],
    [0, 100, 100]]

print np.isin(c,a)

# [[False False  True]
#  [ True False False]]
```

You'll probably want to use np.all() at the end if you're looking for the entire element to be in the test array.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @AturSams This is not probably what is expected. The matches are regardles the item position and `np.all()` with `np.isin()` will not do what you probably expect as [soo-zie pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64692779/320437)

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not have enough reputation to comment but the answer suggested by @rp0 using np.isin and then np.all will not work with numpy arrays.
Counter Example:

```
a = np.array([[[2, 3, 0],
               [1, 0, 1]],
              [[3, 2, 0],
               [0, 1, 1]],
              [[2, 2, 0],
               [1, 1, 1]],
              [[1, 3, 0],
               [2, 0, 1]],
              [[3, 1, 0],
               [0, 2, 1]]])
b = [[3, 2, 0],
     [0, 1, 1]]

c = [[3, 3, 3],
     [3, 3, 3]]

print(np.isin(b,a))
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]]

print(np.isin(c,a))
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]]
```

For completeness, I converted the array to python list using tolist and then used normal 'in' operator and its worked just as expected.

```
print(b in a.lolist())
True

print(c in a.tolist())
False
```