# Return index in Python "in" operator

Tags: python, numpy

When using the "in" operator to check whether an element exist in a numpy array, is there any way to also get the index of that element? Thank you

Comment: If you actually did mean numpy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array

Comment: A recent SO about `in` for `numpy` arrays.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452843/in-operator-for-numpy-arrays.  For 1d arrays there is a `np.in1d` function.  For multidimensional arrays the question is harder.