# How to check if an array is in another array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I thought that `in` would be good for this but it returns true in places where it shouldn't. For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([])

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        a = np.append(a,[i,j])
a = np.reshape(a,(9,2))
print(a)

print([[0,40]] in a)
```

will print true. I cannot understand why it does this... is it because 0 is in the list? I'd like to have something that only prints true if the entire array is in the list.

I want to have my list

```
[[0,1],
[0,2]]
```

and only return true if exactly `[0,x]` (same shape same order) is in it.

Comment: Side note: you can more efficiently construct `a` by `three = np.arange(3.0); np.array([np.repeat(three, 3), np.tile(three, 3)]).T`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452843/in-operator-for-numpy-arrays) is a related question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
([0, 40] == a).all(1).any()
```

The first step is to compute a 2D boolean array of where the matches are.  Then you find the rows where all elements are true.  Then you check if any rows are fully matching.

Answer (score 1):

This code can help you:

```
my_list = [0, 40]
print(all(b in a for b in my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.isin(a_array, b_array) ,it returned a boolean array.
for example:

```
import numpy as np
a_array =np.array([1,2,3,4])
b_array = np.array([3,4,5])
bool_a_b = np.isin(a_array, b_array)
print(bool_a_b)
```

Output:

[False False  True  True]