# Check if array is part of a bigger array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to check if a 1 dimensional numpy array is a part of a bigger, 2 dimensional array. I could do this with many for-loops but I guess there is a more pythonic way to do so.

The attempt I have to far:

```
1darray = np.array([0,0,0])
2darray = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]) 
1darray in 2darray
```

But this code returns a **True**
, as long as one of the elements from 1darray occures somewhere in 2darray. But I want to check if the whole array is a row in the bigger one, so I would want this code to return **False**, while I would want this code to return **True**:

```
1darray = np.array([0,0,1])
2darray = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]) 
1darray in 2darray
```

I would appreciate any help, Thanks already!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an array is in another array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782731/how-to-check-if-an-array-is-in-another-array-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `any()` and `all()` function to achieve this.

```
>>> a=np.array([0,0,0])
>>> b=np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]])
>>> (a == b).all(axis=1).any()
False

>>> a=np.array([0,0,1])
>>> b=np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]])
>>> (a == b).all(axis=1).any()
True
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for.