# finding the occurrence of vector v (1,k) inside a matrix M (m,k)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to find the number of occurrences of vector v  in matrix M.

What I have is a matrix the size (60K, 10)
and I initialised a test vector v (1,10):

```
tester = np.zeros((1, 10))
```

Now I want to check how much time that vector entirely repeats itself in the matrix rows.

I did it iterative and it works, but the fact that the matrix is very large, it affects the performance and im trying to find some more elegant and faster way.

would appreciate some help
Thanks.

Comment: Ive, tried both of the solution and they both did the trick!

Comment: Related: [In operator for numpy arrays] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452843/in-operator-for-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
temp = np.where((prediction == tester)).all(axis=1))
len(temp[0])
```

what **np.where()** returns in the case it has no values [x,y] accept for the condition is the indices, in your case it will return the True and False option, starting from the True.

so using this will sure to lower your running time, and for me its much more elegant then looping through the matrix.

you can check np.where api:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: I don't think this works. When I tried it on the random data I generated I got `68`, and there were only `50` rows in the generated data. I believe this calculates the number of times two matching elements are the same.

Comment: you are absolutely correct I forgot to add all() method **fixed it**

Answer (score 1):

Just compare and use `all`, so each row will result in a `True` value only if all its elements compare equal to the reference array. Then, you can simply sum the result, since `int(True) == 1`.

Example:

```
np.random.seed(0)

data = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(50, 3))
to_match = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(1, 3))

print(to_match)
print((data == to_match).all(axis=1).sum())
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0]]
4
```

...which means that there are 4 instances of `[0, 0, 0]` in `data`.