# sklearn train_test_split returns some elements in both test/train

Tags: scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have a data-set `X` with 260 unique observations.

when running `x_train,x_test,_,_=test_train_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)` I would assume that 
`[p for p in x_test if p in x_train]` would be empty, but it is not. Actually it turns out that only two observations in `x_test` is not in `x_train`.

Is that intended or...?

EDIT (posted the data I am using):

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as split
import numpy as np

DATA=load_breast_cancer()
X=DATA.data
y= DATA.target
y=np.array([1 if p==0 else 0 for p in DATA.target])

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=split(X,y,test_size=0.2,stratify=y,random_state=42)

len([p for p in x_test if p in x_train]) #is not 0
```

EDIT 2.0: Showing that the test works

```py
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b=np.array([[1,2,3],[11,12,13]])

len([p for p in a if p in b]) #1
```

Comment: can you post a full reproducible example? the intersection of train and test should be empty.

Comment: Editted the question now with the data

Comment: If I use the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/find-the-row-indexes-of-several-values-in-a-numpy-array i.e `np.where((x_test==x_train[:,None]).all(-1))[1]` that returns `[]` (that the intersect is empty). But I do think that `[p for p in x_test if p in x_train]` should do the trick

Comment: clearly `[p for p in x_test if p in x_train]` does not do the trick, because it gives different results than `np.where((x_test==x_train[:,None]).all(-1))[1]`. As to why this is, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452843/in-operator-for-numpy-arrays

Comment: Okay, but we do agree that if `x_test` has some values in `x_train` then `[p for p in x_test if p in x_train]` would be non-empty (and logically the other way round)? I mean that the way I test if the two sets intersection is empty is correct

Comment: Right, I agree, and you would be correct if you were working with lists. I also agree that this is counter-intuitive. The test assumes assumes that the `in` operator works like it does on, say a list of tuples, but it doesn't for numpy arrays.

As an example, consider `[p for p in [tuple(x) for x in x_test] if p in [tuple(x) for x in x_train]]`, which does what you want (and gives an empty intersection, as expected)

Comment: I cannot see if the problem is in the test_train_split or where it is. Because the set should be unique (`len(X)==len(np.unique(X,axis=0)`) thus I can really not see where the problem is

Comment: the problem is definitely not in `train_test_split`, it is in your use of the `in` operator in `len([p for p in x_test if p in x_train])`. The `in` operator does not do what you want it to do in this case, because both `x_test` and `x_train` are arrays.

Comment: If you see my edit 2.0, that should show that it works with np.arrays (or did I missunderstand you?)

Comment: Try the same with: `a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]); b=np.array([[5,5,5]])`, it will still return `True`. The `in` operator does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Aaaah! Now I see! Thank you so much - would you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug with the implementation of `train_test_split` in `sklearn`, but a weird peculiarity of how the `in` operator works on numpy arrays. The `in` operator first does an elementwise comparison between two arrays, and returns `True` if ANY of the elements match.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = np.array([[6, 7, 8], [5, 5, 5]])
a in b # True
```

The correct way to test for this kind of overlap is using the equality operator and `np.all` and `np.any`. As a bonus, you also get the indices that overlap for free.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = np.array([[6, 7, 8], [5, 5, 5], [7, 8, 9]])
a in b # True

z = np.any(np.all(a == b[:, None, :], -1))  # False

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = np.array([[6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]])
a in b # True

overlap = np.all(a == b[:, None, :], -1)
z = np.any(overlap)  # True
indices = np.nonzero(overlap)  # (1, 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to check using the following:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as split
import numpy as np

DATA=load_breast_cancer()
X=DATA.data
y= DATA.target
y=np.array([1 if p==0 else 0 for p in DATA.target])

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=split(X,y,test_size=0.2,stratify=y,random_state=42)

len([p for p in x_test.tolist() if p in x_train.tolist()])
0
```

**Using `x_test.tolist()` the `in` operator will work as intended.**

Reference: [testing whether a Numpy array contains a given row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194/testing-whether-a-numpy-array-contains-a-given-row)

Comment: So if you use the breast_cancer data you get the same behaviour? I first thought that maybe the data set isn't unique but `len(X)==len(np.unique(X)) #True`, so I cannot see what can be the problem?

Comment: this is not an sklearn bug, so you should not report it on the issue tracker.