# numpy array in numpy array evaluation to true when it shouldn't?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Does any one have any idea why the below is evaluating to True?

```
board[y_new:y_new + self.size, x_new:x_new + self.size]


array([[[ 75,   0, 130],
        [ 75,   0, 130],
        [ 75,   0, 130]],
       [[ 75,   0, 130],
        [ 75,   0, 130],
        [ 75,   0, 130]],
       [[ 75,   0, 130],
        [ 75,   0, 130],
        [ 75,   0, 130]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Above is my array.

When I check if a value is in the array `col = np.array([255,   0,  64])` like this...

```
col in board[y_new:y_new + self.size, x_new:x_new + self.size]
```

I get

`True`

Its early in the morning and I still need my coffee but this makes NO sense to me right now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["In" operator for numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452843/in-operator-for-numpy-arrays). The gist is, `in` does not work as you expect it to do for numpy arrays.

Comment: Not fully, but its a good start. Thanks

Comment: To me it looked like it was the exact same problem. What is not answered there?

Comment: I'll get back to you, I've now worked out the issue. My current solution is finding the 0 that is contained in both and evaluating to true. Your post is getting me on the right track. Maybe I'm missing something, I haven't tried all options on there yet. Will let you know

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I stand corrected. It perfectly solved my issue in the end. Thanks