# python "in" function works differently for lists and numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

If I have a list of tuples, the "in" function tells me exactly whether the tuple is in the list.

```
>>> a = [(1,2),(3,4)]

>>> (1,2) in a
True

>>> (1,3) in a
False
```

That's what I want. But when I do the same thing for `b = np.array(a)`, both give `True`:

```
>>> b = np.array(a)

>>> (1,2) in b
True

>>> (1,3) in b
True
```

So it seems as though the `in` function for numpy arrays does not check the tuple anymore, but the single values.

1. Why is this?
2. How can I achive a truth request regarding whether a 2d element is in a numpy array as in the example above?

Comment: Operators work differently for *all* types. You would not expect ``+`` to work the same for integers, lists and strings, would you?

Comment: Ok sure, you're right. Then my question is the 2. only.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320624/how-does-contains-work-for-ndarrays)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["In" operator for numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452843/in-operator-for-numpy-arrays)

Comment: Thanks! So it's clear it doesn't work for arrays as I need it. But what's the alternative for arrays? Looping through the single elements would take too much time, I suppose, would it not? I need to handle a lot of tuples (3.6e6 times 10)

Comment: Are the contents of your tuples always small integers?

Comment: yes, the contents are always small integers

Comment: Of course, **there are no `tuple` objects in your array**. Why do you *expect* this to work at all??

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki thanks you. np.isin doesn't help, it does the same as in, but the first answer is probably the solution. I don't understand it, though, but I have to try, then. Thanks

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why are there no tuple objects in my array anymore?

Comment: @Interferenzbrille_ why do you think there should be any? What would be the point of creating the array? Numpy arrays are wrappers over primitive arrays. They do not contain *python objects at all* (unless you specify dtype=object, but a dtype=object array is just a less performant python list)

Comment: To efficiently check if a "row" is in an array, then probably you can convert to a flattened structured dtype, then convert the tuples to scalars of that same dtype

Comment: You could try to use pure Python set difference to get decent performance in this case. For example, if `data = set([(1,2), (1,3)])` and `query = set([(1,2),(1,3)])`, you could compute  `query - data` fairly fast (.4 seconds for 3 million 10-tuples in my case).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought they would contain stuff, but yes, makes sense that they don't. Thanks!

Comment: how about     (1,3) in np.array(a).tolist() ?

Comment: (1,3) in np.array(a).tolist() gives False, (1,2) in np.array(a).tolist() does as well, though. Thanks yall! I concluded, for what I wanted to do, I just need lists.